# How to decide which certificates to trust?

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 15.10

When upgrading from 15.04 to 15.10, the ca-certificates-configuration askes me nicely to tick off all new certificates I am going to trust.

Although it is nice to ask, it gives me no hint how to decide which to trust? Any hint for me?